# Use macro in different file

Tags: module, macros, rust

I'm building a library and I have the following structure:

src/lib.rs

```
mod a;
mod b;
```

src/b.rs:

```
macro_rules! x ...
```

src/a.rs:

```
x!()
```

this doesn't work. I tried to fiddle with `#macro_export` and `#macro_use` but without success. What's the correct approach to re-using macros in the same library but in different module and file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order for macros from submodules to be visible to "sibling" modules they have to be declared in a certain order, that is, the module with macros should be declared the first. It also should have `#[macro_use]` attribute attached. This should work:

```
#[macro_use] mod b;
mod a;
```

`#[macro_use]` attribute makes macros from the module visible to all code "below" the module declaration, that's why your original variant could not possibly work.